# How do I upload files to Azure Web App Virtual Directories

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-webapps

I created some virtual directories in my azure web app and downloaded the publish profile which contains the credentials for me to connect to the web app. I connected via FTP using filezilla but cannot see any of the virtual directories. All I see site/wwwroot. In the web app i created virtual directories for test1 using virtual path : /test1, physical path : site\wwwroot\test1. However i cant see these when logged onto FTP with filezilla??

Comment: They don't get created for you since `wwwroot` is treated as immutable and is left totally under your control when deploying.

Comment: ah so i will need to create them manually?

Comment: They should be part of your deployment. If your deployment is a manual file copy operation, then yes.